# Trying to establish a trigger that counts rows after every update

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables: SKN_ENJIN, and SKN_ENJIN_COUNT

SKN_ENJIN keeps track of usernames and emails.
SKN_ENJIN_COUNT is being used to populate a chart for a dashboard report.

I created this trigger earlier today:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_SKN_ENJIN_COUNT_TG" 
  after insert or update or delete on "SKN_ENJIN"               

  DECLARE
  mCount    NUMBER;
  mDate     DATE;

begin 

  select COUNT(ID) into mCount from SKN_ENJIN where Status = 1;

  select TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') into mDate from dual;

  MERGE INTO SKN_ENJIN_COUNT c
      USING dual d
      ON (c.Count_date = mDate)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET c.Member_count = mCount
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Count_date, Member_count)
      VALUES (mDate, mCount);
end;
```

Up until about 10 minutes ago, the trigger worked beautifully. Suddenly, the trigger started throwing `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

I have tried changing `CURRENT_DATE` to `SYSDATE()`, I have tried changing `TO_DATE` to `TO_CHAR`. These approaches seemed to cause more errors to appear. What am I missing, and what should I change to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to call `TO_DATE` on `CURRENT_DATE` or `SYSDATE`.  These functions already return `DATE`s, so there's no need to do any conversion.

In fact, calling `TO_DATE` on something that is already a `DATE` forces Oracle to convert it to a string using NLS settings (`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`) and the convert it back to a date using a given date format picture.  If the date format picture you are using does not match `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, you will likely end up with errors or incorrect values.

Instead of writing

```
  select TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') into mDate from dual;
```

you can write

```
  select CURRENT_DATE into mDate from dual;
```

or just

```
  mDate := CURRENT_DATE;
```

I don't know what type of the `Count_date` column in your `SKN_ENJIN_COUNT` table is, but if it is `DATE`, it is similarly incorrect to call `TO_DATE` on it.

Comment: I ended up making the format stipulation because the trigger was not merging properly as it identified by the second.

Comment: @Thelnternet So you are converting between datatypes (twice) in order to truncate a date down to the day? Why not just [`trunc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) the date?

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution while stumbling my way through it
. It seems that the format of the date is extremely important. Earlier my formatting had been `DD-MM-YYYY`, when I used `MM-DD-YYYY` and just a touch of refactoring (`ON (TO_DATE(c.Count_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = TO_DATE(mDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'))` the script worked without a fuss.

```
  select COUNT(ID) into mCount from SKN_ENJIN where Status = 1;

  select sysdate into mDate from dual;

  MERGE INTO SKN_ENJIN_COUNT c
      USING dual d
      ON (TO_DATE(c.Count_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = TO_DATE(mDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET c.Member_count = mCount
```

Comment: Seriously, don't convert dates to strings without a format as this relies on `nls_date_format` and `nls_date_language`. Even if it works today it might fail in the future, as these settings are session-dependant.